# toggleClass on click or change of child input

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to toggle the `.active` class and check the input when either the `.item` div is **clicked** or the input is **checked**. Currently the function stops when the input is checked.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".item", function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  if (target.is("#" + id + " input:checkbox")) {
    return;
  }
  if (target.is("button")) {
    return;
  }
  var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
  checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.is(":checked"));
  $(this).closest(".item").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.item.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="first">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button>button</button>
</div>
<div class="item" id="second">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You've told it to. `if (target.is("#" + id + " input:checkbox")) { return; }` exits the event handler if the target of the click event is the checkbox.

Comment: If I remove that the checkbox doesn't check when I click it.

Comment: So what's the actual goal here? When you click the div or check the input the div should get the active class and the input should be checked? And clicking the div or unchecking the input should remove the active class? What should the button do?

Comment: @j08691 correct. The button is to show that some items nested inside the .item are clickable and won't toggle the input or active class when they're clicked

Comment: This seems like confusing UX. There's a reason HTML forbids nesting interactive elements like buttons and anchors; to prevent exactly these kinds of problems. It would be better (UX, a11y) to give the checkbox a `label` and have clicking on the label or the checkbox toggle the checkbox.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I basically want the checkbox to be checked when either the checkbox itself is checked OR the item is clicked. And every time each checkbox is checked, add the active class to the item.